# Sqlite select * from multiple tables

Tags: sqlite

I really need some help with sqlite.

I have one database with two tables, lets call them table1 and table2.
These two tables are the same basically, same column names and same amount of columns.

First column is TEXT and the rest is double, this applies for both tables.

I don't want to combine them into one table. If new information should arise that normally should go into table1 I want to insert it to table2.

The problem is when I use select to search in both tables like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2
```

But this does not work. I just want to print those tables together.
How do I do this?

Comment: How about joining those tables by id?

Comment: Sounds as if you are looking for `union all`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`. The first removes duplicates from the result set, the second one doesn't.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2
```