# Connect the different tables form one Sqlite file by using python

Tags: python, sqlite

So sorry, i have one sqlite file and it includes many tables(Like table_A to table_Z)
Sorry, i only can use the c.execute('SELECT ST_Name FROM table_A') and do table_B again.

How can i use the loop to do it, i already search all day, but i don't get the answer, please help me.

Thx!!

About my code, please refer below

```
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
Sqlite_Path = 'D:\Student.sqlite'
conn = sqlite3.connect(Sqlite_Path)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT ST_Name FROM Table_A')
data = c.fetchall()

# do something

c.execute('SELECT ST_Name FROM Table_B')
data = c.fetchall()
# do something again
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088815/sqlite-select-from-multiple-tables

Comment: Are you trying to iteratively query all tables in a DB? If so, can't you simply generate the appropariate SQL query by concatenating two strings?

Comment: sorry, i think maybe i write one list Tables = [Table_A, Table_B, Table_C]
for x in range(1:3):
c.execute('SELECT ST_Name FROM Tables[x]')
data = c.fetchall()
# do something

Comment: You really need to work through a Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework to me, but anyway:

```
tables = ["Table_A ", "Table_B", "Table_C"]
for table in tables:
    c.execute('SELECT ST_Name FROM {}'.format(table))
    data = c.fetchall()
    # do something
```

Comment: Thanks your support, i already graduated many years, i just have interest in program language, so i study by myself.

But i still thanks for your help, again.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know all the tables or for some other reason you can do something like this:

```
tables = [r[0] for r in db.execute('select name from sqlite_master where name like "table_%" and type = "table"')]
for table in tables:
    stmt = 'SELECT * FROM {};'.format(table)
    c = db.execute(stmt)
    rows = c.fetch_all()
    # ... do something with results
```

this returns **ALL** table names in your sqlitefile